# Add arrows and autoplay to owl carousel template

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

I downloaded a template for owl.carousel.min.js - I have no idea how to add autoplay and arrows.

It's on a test server on http://testing.r2group.co.za/Test/index.html about halfway down. I would appreciate ANY help, as I'm proficient with HTML, but the JS is beyond me. (why I downloaded a template)

Answer (score 0):

Have you found documentation for how to use the carousel? That is a good place to start.

The owl is part of a theme I am using. Looks like this javascript is included after the carousel.

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $("#latest_news .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        lazyLoad: true,
        responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
        slideSpeed: 500,
        paginationSpeed: 500,
        scrollPerPage: true,
        stopOnHover: true,
        rewindNav: true,
        rewindSpeed: 600,
        pagination: true,
        navigation: false,
        autoPlay: true,
        singleItem: true
    });
});
</script>
```

This tells the browser to start a new script with jQuery.

```
jQuery(function($){
    //code
});
```

Inside this function is specific to Owl Carousel.

`$("latest_news .owl-carousel")` selects the proper element. This is where you will use your own CSS selectors to get your slider.

It is being passed a javascript object of parameters for the slider. For your autoplay, you can give it

```
$("#YOUR-ELEMENT .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true
});
```

The arrows are also described by a setting in this object. Looks like the left/right arrows can be added like this:

```
$("#YOUR-ELEMENT .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigationText:["<i class='icon-left-open'></i>","<i class='icon-right-open'></i>"]
});
```

**So, at a minimum to get your arrows and autoplay, your script should look like this:**

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#YOUR-ELEMENT .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            autoplay: true,
            navigationText:["<i class='icon-left-open'></i>","<i class='icon-right-open'></i>"]
        });
    });
</script>
```

It would be worth looking at which other settings you can change for greater customization. The slideSpeed and rewindSpeed, for example, could be a good place to get familiar playing with javascript.

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a bash

Comment: My JS code looks a little different to yours. Its resident in a separate js file:

Comment: @Michelle, it is okay if scripts live in a separate file. Just make sure that you include a link to the script like this `<script src="path/to/script.js"></script>` . Typically you want to have these at the bottom of your HTML document, right before closing the body tag. 
Did the code work? It would be great if you update your question to include samples of what you have tried and the code that exists.